# Add column to show rows with close time differences without cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a `Date_Time` column and want to identify groups of close date differences and identify them by incrementing numbers if the difference is greater than 10 minutes.

I could do this with a cursor, but want something more efficient.

Sample data:

```
Foo               Bar
----------------  ---  
8/23/12 12:05 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:08 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:11 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:15 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:20 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:24 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:28 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:32 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:36 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:39 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:42 PM    1  
8/23/12 12:45 PM    1  
8/23/12 4:01 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:05 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:08 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:11 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:14 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:20 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:23 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:28 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:33 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:36 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:40 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:44 PM     2  
8/23/12 4:47 PM     2  
8/23/12 8:01 PM     3
```

Comment: Please specify your version of SQL Server; if 2012 or newer, then you can do this with `LAG`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. SQL 2014

Comment: Was a cursor inefficient, or do you just *think* a cursor would be inefficient? Did you try it? Could you show what you tried? Also it's unclear to me if `Bar` is the output column you want, or `Bar` is in the table and needs to be used in some way, or something else. If you've shown the data in the table, could you show the desired results? If those *are* the desired results based on the column `Foo`, could you explain why `Bar` doesn't increment between 12:05 PM and 12:45 PM? That's more than 10 minutes.

Comment: I think a cursor would be inefficient.  Bar is what I am looking to add and is not part of the data in the table.  The table is the desired output.  I'd like to set the threshold for time gaps.  The 12:05pm to 12:45pm is a mistake in my example.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i feel like this is an XY problem.  what are you trying to solve with this?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well fix the data in your question please, so we can actually understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question at this time, I assume you have a list of dates and times, and you want to assign a sequential number to them, with the same number assigned to all values where the previous value is no more than 10 minutes less than the current value, as shown in the desired results.

Let's assume your table of date time values is `myDtTm`, and the column name is `theDateTime`

```
SELECT theDateTime
      ,SUM(TimeDiff) OVER (ORDER BY theDateTime)
  FROM (
        SELECT
               theDateTime
              ,CASE WHEN COALESCE(DATEDIFF( minute
                                           ,LAG(theDateTime, 1)
                                             OVER (ORDER BY theDateTime)
                                           ,theDateTime
                                          ), 100000) > 10 --< this is the max time diff
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END as TimeDiff
          FROM myDtTm
       ) sq
 ORDER BY theDateTime
;
```

This [dbfiddle.uk link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=920b573556afc279224880faac4562a0) shows this in action, providing precisely the results shown in the question.

Explanation:

In the sub-query, we use the window function `LAG` to compare each date and time to the one before it, and figure out how many minutes' difference there is. We assign 1 to `TimeDiff` for the current date if the difference more than the target (ten minutes), and 0 otherwise. (Note: we get back NULL for the first row, because there is no previous row at that point; if you have NULL datetime values in your data, you may need to change this).

Then, we simply do a rolling total (`SUM` of `TimeDiff` over our datetime value gives us a total of `TimeDiff` for this row and all previous rows).

Note: I took the idea from [this DBA.SE question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149174/116653); the differences were notable enough that I don't think this is a duplicate.